# Form Validation using Javascript one form different variations

Tags: javascript

I've been developing a publications application that has a drop down menu where you choose one of the publications types the form then changes(using jquery) to show and hide fields that are required. For example:

```
Every Publication:   
Title 

Conference:  
Start Date  
End Date

Journal:  
Volume  
Number
```

What i am wondering is how i could get form validation to work so that it doesn't say one of the journal paper fields are required when the user is inputting a conference paper.
Thanks in Advance,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the value of the dropdown to determine which validation rules to run:

```
var type = $('#your-select').val();
if(type == "conference"){
    // conference validation rules
} else if (type == "journal"){
    // journal validation rules
}
```

Or check if a field is hidden.  If no, run validation on it:

```
if(!$('#your-field').is(':hidden')){
    // run validation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation plugin works on classes?

input type="text" class="validate" ...

If you do a check: 
if paper = conference paper
then remove class from "not more required" fields